# Clone git use HTTP in Local from AWS EC2

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, git-http-backend

I made AWS EC2 and succeeded in clone with ssh.

Here is example.

git clone ssh://ubuntu@:/home/ubuntu/git/chm/

Clone was successful at local with the following instructions, and all commits and push are possible.

However, I want to perform the clone without password using http.

I tried googling so many time, but I experienced timeout when I performed the clone.

If you know how to do it, I would really appreciate it if you could let me know in detail.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to install a webserver capable of providing git over http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with apache2!!!!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with apache2!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).